# Orchard Layout designer doesn't appear

Tags: orchardcms

I've got some problem with orchard, the case is, when i add input filed with type of MediaLibraryPickerField (This is to upload image) in my content, Layout designer disappears when creating new page, if i delete input filed than i appears.

I'm not customizing anything, both are orchards core functionalities, does someone have any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logs for exceptions: there's probably one that is preventing the editor from displaying properly. If that's the case, and only Orchard code is on the stack trace, then please file a bug.